# Bottom Navigation Gets Stuck While ProgressBar Dialog Shows

Tags: android, xamarin.android, progressdialog, android-progressbar, bottomnavigationview

Can anyone please suggest about below issue.

Actually i'm unable to navigate through BottomNavigationView option while progressbar dialog gets display.

Is it any way to resize the height of dialog upto BottomNavigationView so that navigation can work?

**ProgressBar Dialog**

```
public class BusyViewOverlay
{
    private bool _isRunning;
    private Dialog dialog;
    public BusyViewOverlay(Context context)
    {
        dialog = new Dialog(context);
        var progressBar = new ProgressBar(context);

        progressBar.Indeterminate = true;
        progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        progressBar.IndeterminateDrawable = context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.progress_animation);
        dialog.Window.SetBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent));
        dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.Window.SetDimAmount(0.0f);
        dialog.SetContentView(progressBar);
    }

    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get => _isRunning;
        set
        {
            _isRunning = value;

            if (_isRunning)
            {
                Show();
            }
            else
            {
                Dismiss();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Show() {
        dialog.Show();
    }

    private void Dismiss() {
        dialog.Dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then the best way I can think of is not to use progress bar dialog rather use progress bar inside your layout and hide it or use visibility.gone, when you need to show it put the visibility to Visible.

Another way to do this is to put your dialog inside a certain layout dynamically.